# Coinduction - clear, concise description

Tags: computer-science, theory

I am studying coinduction(*not* induction) as part of a class on static analysis. Rummaging around the internet, I am simply not finding clear, concise description of:

- What coinduction is
- How coinduction actually proves something(it seems that coinduction is like waving a magic hand in the treatments I've read)
- What propositions require coinductive proof
- How to operate a coinductive proof

Comment: There's a terse page at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coinduction with some onwards links - is that any help?

Comment: @Jonathan: Well, no. To someone who understood this area already, it might be a lot of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coinduction is induction along the steps of a computation or process. If something holds for every step, then it holds for the infinite computation and its possibly infinite resulting data structure.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding (which may be wrong) goes like this:

Coinduction is a way to prove things about infinite data structures.

Just like induction, it seems like cheating at first. The key thing to realize is that instead of:

1. proving that something works for the base cases
2. proving that it works for each "single step", under the assumption that it works for all (finite) cases
3. then claiming that it therefore works for all (finite) cases (this is induction)

you instead:

1. prove, under the assumption that it works for all non-finite cases, that it works for each "single step"
2. claim that it therefore works for all non-finite cases (this is coinduction, and it's justified since each non-finite case is a (finite) sequence of single steps followed by a non-finite part which works by hypothesis)

Coinduction is a useful proof technique for establishing structurally "obvious" propositions about infinite data structures. Unfortunately (or not?) the fact that it's commonly useful for proving "obvious" things makes it harder to see how it is proving anything at all and not just hand-waving.

[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.1418) is helpful in some ways, and confusing in others (at least those uninitiated in category theory, among whom I count myself).

Comment: Sadly for you, the Packers just lost. :rim shot:

Comment: But seriously, folks... I agree, that paper is extremely confusing and is still one of the better explanations I have come across.

Comment: I really need to learn category theory - it keeps popping up everywhere, and it's really annoying that I don't understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Coinduction is a little easier to understand in the context of logic programming. I recommend the following tutorial paper: Coinductive Logic Programming and its Applications by Gupta et al that appeared in the Proc. of International Conference on Logic Programming 2007. Just as recursion corresponds to induction (least fixpoint semantics), co-recursion corresponds to coinduction (greatest fixpoint semantics). One can think of co-recursion as "recursion without a base case". In the absence of a base case, the termination criteria has to be based on recognizing cycles in the computation (a rational infinite proof). More details are in the tutorial paper.